# SSL connection to AWS RDS Postgresql instance from windows client

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws, ssl

I am trying to connect to a PG instance hosted on AWS RDS using a secure SSL connection. Where do I store the public key on windows so that it is automatically applied to the connection?

Please note that when I open PGAdmin it only lets me specify .crt and .key files. Is there a way to point it to .pem files?

I downloaded the public key referenced here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

On Linux it is a simple matter of putting this key into the default OpenSSL directory and postgres seems to detect it and take care of the rest itself.

On Windows I have not figured out how to do this or where to store the .pem file or how to point PGAdmin to a .pem file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer! Turns out that the connection was encrypted all along, I just didn't realize it. Boy did that make me feel stupid. I ended up downloading Wireshark and sniffing my packets just to make sure.

Note that this applies to ssl-mode "require", but in order to use ssl-mode "verify-full" you do still need a root cert. In this case I just took the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` and renamed it from .pem to .crt. This allowed me to point to the file from the SSL tab of the connection properties window in PGAdmin.

Doing this I was able to specify ssl-mode "verify-full" and connect to my instance.

Edit:

By default RDS Postgres WILL accept non-SSL connections. It just happens that PGAdmin was initiating an SSL connection by default.

> ... if you don't provide the ssl mode then postgres
>   connects with default mode as 'prefer' (please refer to documentation
>   mentioned above), according to which, it will prefer ssl connection,
>   but if not available, it will connect with non-ssl connection as well.
>   [Source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236594)

To make sure you are always using SSL you can set the parameter `rds.force_ssl` to be 1 (on). [More details.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.Requiring)

Comment: if I rename the `.pem` file to `.crt` and add it as the Server Root Certificate file, I get an `SSL error: tlsv` alert unknown ca` in pgAdmin III

Comment: It will be great if you could post some screen shots of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PGAdmin, when you create a new connection there is a tab called `SSL`[1]. There you can input your pem file.

If you are using `psql`, put your `pem`file on `%APPDATA%\postgresql\` directory. See more details at the documentation[2].

Hope it helps.

References:

1. https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect.html?highlight=ssl
2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-ssl.html

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. When I open PGAdmin it only lets me specify .crt and .key files. Is there a way to point it to .pem files? Or do I need to convert the pem to a crt/key somehow?

Comment: The first link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

In pgAdmin:

Just load the `pem` file as the "Root certificate", in my case, it is a root certificate called `ca.pem`. Worked for me.

*(Not sure about the SSL compression, I just clicked it as well, should work without it.)*

[image]

[image]